# How to pass a link to req.flash() in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, connect-flash

I have been trying to figure out a way of passing a link in req.flash() in my js file, without actually doing that in html template, because am using the alert message as a partial in other html pages, I wish to pass in resend verification link, is there a way around this, or do i really have to create another req.flash for verify

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    res.locals.success = req.flash("success")
    next();
})

router.get("/verification", function(req,res){
    verification coding stuff here
})
```

*the verification route is the link that i wish to pass in the req.flash('error')*

```
router.get('/verify/:token', function(req,res){
  User.findOne({ verificationToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now()}}, function(err, user){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
          //here is where i wish to pass in the link for verification link//
          req.flash('error', 'Mail verify token is invalid or has expired' + resend link here + '.')
          return res.redirect('/forgot')
      } else {
          user.active = "true"
          user.save()
          console.log(user.active);
          req.flash('success', 'Your mail have been verified successfully')
          res.redirect('/login');
      }
  })
})

<% if(error && error.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible deposit-alert" role="alert">
        <div class="container">
            <%= error %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: To also do the same with handlebars. Just wrap the message in `{{{}}}` triple curl braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work for you.

**Controller::**

```
router.get('/verify/:token', function(req,res){
  User.findOne({ verificationToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now()}}, function(err, user){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
          //here is where i wish to pass in the link for verification link//
          var link  = '/verification/';
          var message =  'Mail verify token is invalid or has expired, <a href="'+ link +'"> Click here to resend the link</a>.'
          req.flash('error',message)
          return res.redirect('/forgot')
      } else {
          user.active = "true"
          user.save()
          console.log(user.active);
          req.flash('success', 'Your mail have been verified successfully')
          res.redirect('/login');
      }
  })
})
```

**Template**
Instead of using `<%= message %>`  use this. `<%- message %>`

```
<% if(error && error.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible deposit-alert" role="alert">
        <div class="container">
          <%- message %> 
        </div>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: thanks for replying, i have tried your solution but it just prints out the same way you wrote it e.g <a href="link"> click </a>  and the link is not working. the req.headers.. is printed out correct with my domain. any other way :) @FarhanTahir

Comment: @FillipoSniper Can you share the screen shot how it appears. and what happens when you click on the link ? mean any error on console or anything ?

Comment: It doesn't show any error, it just flashes it the same way with other text as if it is a normal text @FarhanTahir

Comment: Share the code which you are using to display the flash message.

Comment: I have just updated my code as you requested, you might wanna check it out @FarhanTahir

Comment: yeah it works out but then i think you should edit your code a bit, in the req.headers.host i don't think if it is needed cause it's just a duplicate of the domain as it redirects to page not found. things work out now :) @FarhanTahir

Comment: @FillipoSniper I'm glad I was able to help, Hey check my answer now removed the req.headers.host.